# why using blur event instead of submit for form data submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was reading klaviyo's [integration guide](https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002451292-Sync-a-Shopify-Signup-Form-to-a-List-in-Klaviyo). The javascript it is using to submit form data is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='contact[email]']").on('blur', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $(this).val();
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/external/subscribe",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "data": {
                "g": "LIST_ID",
                "$fields": "$source",
                "email": email,
                "$source": "Shopify form"
            }
        };
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am wondering why it is using the "blur" event instead of user's clicking on "submit" button to trigger the ajax function. I think with this code, if user opt out of the form's text-box prematurely without clicking "sign up" or "submit", the data will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

*"I am wondering why it is using the "blur" event instead of user's clicking on "submit" button to trigger the ajax function."*

Because this two ways will give you two different behaviors. Very simple:

1. When you use `click` event, the function will be executed after button click
2. When you use `blur` event, the function will be executed after the input will lose it's focus

Answer (score 0):

The blur event fires when the element loses focus and potentially 'after' the email is typed in it gets sent. This is helpful with conversions from dropoffs in general.

Comment: I don't understand how this is "helpful with conversions from dropoffs"? Could you please explain? Besides, if the user accidentally hit tab when he is typing email, aren't we getting some useless informations? By the way I don't see the validation in the codes.

Comment: If a user was to start filling the input field out and inputted their email address, you could send the email immediately after it was typed and the blur event fired from the element loosing focus. Yea, you're correct in that tab could be hit and this wouldn't work. This information could be helpful in retaining users that dropped off and decided not to hit the "submit" button. I will take another look at their code though.